# Determine the minimum number of integers in a complete sequence of $n$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n$ be an even positive integer. A sequence of $n$ real numbers is called complete if for every integer $m$ with $1 \leq m \leq n$ either the sum of the first $m$ terms of the sum or the sum of the last $m$ terms is integral. Determine the minimum number of integers in a complete sequence of $n$ numbers.

---

I know the answer is 2. I have already proved the answer can't be $1$ (not including the proof here as it's not relevant here). Now, to prove that $2$ is the answer I need to show a construction involving 2 integers. First of all, the two integers must sit both together either at front, or at last (otherwise, in case of $m=2$, we get contradiction). Assume they both are at front, so that automatically works out $m=1,2$, now for $m=3$, we can take numbers like $2/3,2/3,2/3$ as the 3 last numbers, but then, for $m=4$, we have to take the sum from beginning, i.e. on the side where we already have 2 integers, now we can take two numbers after it, for example $1/2,1/2$. So, in this way we keep building up rhe sequence from both direction, but we run into problem, when $m \geq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, cuz now, we would have some elements from "both sides of" $a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ ($a_k$ is the kth element of the sequence.) How do I nake sure, every such $m \geq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ will result in an integral sum?

Comment: How do you know the answer to be $2$? And your proof that the answer can't be $1$ is relevant, please share it.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity well, are you asking for proof why the answer is 2? As I said, I'm still looking for the construction needed to show 2 is possible, and I know 2 is possible as it's the answer given in book. Otherwise, if you want to dismiss whether 2 is the answer or not, you may start the problem from scratch

Comment: I want to see your work!

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity ok, give me some time, i will add my tries (unsuccessful) in proving 2 indeed works.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity i have edited in my attempt.

Comment: Are you assuming that there is one minimum for all $n$?  For $n=2$, of course you need two, but I don't think it's obvious for higher $n$.  After all, if odd numbers were allowed, then $[1,.5,.5]$ works for $n=3$.  If you have proven than $1$ fails for all even $n$, it's worth including that argument in your post.

Comment: @lulu As it turns out, there is indeed one minimum for all $n$. $\quad$ Also, OP indicated that they "have edited in my attempt" prior to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Construct the function $f: \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n \} \rightarrow \{ \{F\}, \{L\}, \{F, L\} \}$ where $f(k)$ states whether the first $k$, last $k$, or both $k$ terms sum to an integer.

Notice that if $f(a) \cap f(a+1) \neq \emptyset$, then this implies that there either the $a+1$ term, or the $n-a$ term, or both is an integer (and we can determine which case by the value of $f(a) \cap f(a+1)$).

To show how this can be used, we state 2 (hopefully obvious) facts:

1. Since $f(0) = \{ F, L \}$, so $ f(0) \cap f(1) \neq \emptyset$. Either the first term, last term, or both is an integer, depending on what $f(1)$ is.
2. Since $f(n) = \{ F, L \}$, so $f(n-1) \cap f(n) \neq \emptyset$, which leads to the same conclusion.

To prove that 2 is a lower bound, show that there is another $a \neq 0, n-1$ where  $f(a) \cap f(a+1) \neq \emptyset$. (OP claims to have a proof, but I don't think it's rigorous.)

> **Hint:** If $f(a) = \{L \}$, what is $ f(n- a) $?

> **Further hint:** We've not used that $n$ is even.

To prove that 2 is the minimum, construct an example for even $n$. The previous step gives further ideas of how to get started.
(To me, this should be obvious/easily guessed, though OP has indicated that they can't find this. )